# Tool to create Call hierarchy of library

Tags: c++, call

I've a very large source code in C++ (written using standard templates). I need to understand it's control flow. It's entry point is `main()` function but within `main()` it calls so many functions (which in turn calls another functions) so it is becoming very hard for me keep track of what goes where. I'm using eclipse to navigate between files and keep track but still it is hard to manage as it contains around 100 `.c` and `.h`files. Is there any tool which can create call hierarchy starting from main(). Although I have 100 files, I know it uses somewhere around 35 files only. I'm on Linux. Can GCC help me with this?

Comment: check doxygen, it should have call diagrams.

Comment: Your `#include` statements should give some information. And you can try leaving some object files out of the executable; if the linker doesn't complain, those files are unnecessary.

Answer (score 7):

List of tools you might use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph

I prefer doxygen: http://www.doxygen.nl/

An example of doxygen call graph from http://www-scf.usc.edu/~peterchd/doxygen/:

[image: call graph]